# React defaultValue and value together in input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Since my form big ,here i am pasting small part of code to understand better.

when i select `username` from `select field` then next disabled `field dob` must populate .So it works fine .

But problem is in my form i have a option called `partial save button` which will save in `local storage` .But this wont populate to dob field when we refresh page.

To fix this i changed value property to `defaultValue` then it will populate data but fails to set value when `onchange select triggers.`

Even i tried both defaultValue and value property together then i get error saying

> index.js:1 Warning: MuiOutlinedInputInput contains an input of type
> text with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be
> either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or
> the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a
> controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these
> props. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

```
<FormControl >
        <InputLabel id="userLabel" >Username</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="userLabel"
          id="userLabelId"

          MenuProps={MenuProps}
          label="Username"
          name="userName"
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleChange(e);
          }}
          value={userDetail.userName ?? ''}

        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {userList ? userList.map((user) => (
            <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id ?? ''}>
              {user.userName}
            </MenuItem>
          )) : null}
        </Select>

      </FormControl>

      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        required
        id="dob"
        label="Date Of birth"
        name="dob"

        value={userDetail.dob ?? ''}

        disabled
      />
```

Comment: initialize `userDetails.dob` to an empty string. If it is null or undefined and then you set it to an empty string then it goes from controlled to uncontrolled and react then screams at you

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal after partial save dob will save in local storage and it preload redux state when user entire page reload.so that time value dob  exist

Comment: right... but you must have a not undefined for `userDetails.dob`. But by `userDetails.dob` being undefined, the component is uncontrolled and then when `userDetails.dob` is not undefined then it becomes controlled. This is why react is screaming at you.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal if i use defaultValue then dob will populate on reload entire page .but when i change user then it wont populate dob field. if i use value property then its visa versa issue

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal could you explain more  with example or solution for my problem since i am new to react.

Comment: So, here's what is happening. When you say `userDetail.dob ?? ''` then you telling this component "Please maintain your own state". So the component says "no problem, I'll be an uncontrolled component". Then you say to the component later, "I'm supplying you a value" & the component says "wait a minute, I'm an uncontrolled component, you can't make me into a controlled component". So, start off by keeping it controlled by supplying it an empty string.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal thanks for finding out my mistake. i wasted one day to solve this .without you i couldnt understood this mistake .you can post as answer. i will upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what is happening. When you say `userDetail.dob ?? ''` and `userDetails.dob == null` then you are telling this component "Please maintain your own state".

So the component says "no problem, I'll be an uncontrolled component".

Then you say to the component later, that is when `userDetails != null`, "I'm supplying you a value" & the component says "wait a minute, I'm an uncontrolled component, you can't make me into a controlled component".

So, start off by keeping it controlled by supplying it an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The value of Select and the value of menuitem must match.
So you have to use userName.

```js
{userList ? userList.map((flock) => (
  <MenuItem key={flock.id} value={flock.userName ?? ''}>
    {flock.userName}
  </MenuItem>
)) : null}
```

Comment: select works fine in both cases .issue only with the dob field doesn't work  as expected